# How to prove $2^{n+1} * 2^{n+1} = (2^n*2^n)+(2^n*2^n)+(2^n*2^n)+(2^n*2^n)$

Tags: proof-verification, induction, area

Below diagram is used as part of a proof of induction to prove that $E$ a way to tile a $2^n * 2^n$ region with square missing :

[image]

What is the proof that $2^{n+1} * 2^{n+1}$ = $(2^n*2^n)+(2^n*2^n)+(2^n*2^n)+(2^n*2^n)$ ?

Comment: $$2^{n+1}\cdot 2^{n+1} = (2\cdot 2^n)\cdot (2\cdot 2^n) = 4(2^n\cdot 2^n)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$2^{n+1}2^{n+1}=(2^n+2^n)(2^n+2^n)=(2^n\times2^n)+(2^n\times2^n)+(2^n\times2^n)+(2^n\times2^n)$$

Comment: what is the rule that gives 2^n+1*2^n+1=(2^n+2^n)*(2^n+2^n)

Comment: The rule is that $2^{n+1}=2\times 2^n=2^n+2^n$, so that $2^{n+1}\times2^{n+1}=(2^n+2^n)(2^n+2^n)$.

Comment: So is also true that $A^{n+1}$ = $A * A^{n}$ ? I think I understand now, this statement is true

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: $A^{n+1}=A*A^n$ is the *definition* of $A^{n+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
(2^{n+1})*(2^{n+1})=(2*2^n)*(2*2^n)=(2*2)*(2^n*2^n)=4*(2^n*2^n)
$$

Comment: @Alijah Ahmed what is the rule that gives 2^n+1* 2^n+1=(2 * 2^n) * (2 * 2^n)

Comment: Simply the definition of integer exponent: $a^{n+1}=a\cdot a^n$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, $a^m\cdot a^n=a^{m+n}$, so $a^n\cdot a^n=a^{n+n}=a^{2n}$. Thus
$$
a^n\cdot a^n+a^n\cdot a^n+a^n\cdot a^n+a^n\cdot a^n=4a^n\cdot a^n=4a^{2n}
$$
Similarly, $a^{n+1}\cdot a^{n+1}=a^{2n+2}$. Now let $a=2$; the former expression is
$$
4\cdot2^{2n}=2^2\cdot2^{2n}=2^{2n+2}
$$